# JQuery validation - show field name in error messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

When displaying error messages, the [JQuery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) plugin is using the `{number}` format as a placeholder for the *parameters* passed to the rules. (e.g. `this field must be between {0} and {1} characters`)

I couldn't, however, figure out a way to pass the *field name* to the message in the global scope, using the `$.validator.messages` array.

so instead of the static:

`this field is required`

I'd like to pass something like:

`the {fieldname} field is required`

In Laravel, my server-side framework, the `:attribute` plcaheholder serves this purpose.
Is this feature supported by the plugin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass a function as the message value like

```
$.validator.messages.required = function (param, input) {
    return 'The ' + input.name + ' field is required';
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/acm5fmks/)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a number of ways to customize your error messages with JQuery Validate.  Altering the the validator prototype is one way but there are more.  Which to use is subject to your end objective.  For instance, how granular you want to be (see below snippet for an example).

Specific documentation on error messages can be found here: https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-error-messages

Full control of each field individually specific to each type of error is available using the **messages** property on the options object passed to validate(). Here's an example copied from https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/ where there's an email field with two validation rules: required and email format...

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    name: "required",
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    name: "Please specify your name",
    email: {
      required: "We need your email address to contact you",
      email: "Your email address must be in the format of  name@domain.com"
    }
  }
});
```